# Hiding Windows Updates based on keywords with PSWindowsUpdate Powershell Module

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, windows-update

I'm attempting to automate the entire update process at the library where I work. I've written a simple script that allows me to both update all of our software packages using Chocolatey and to perform Windows updates using the PSWindowsUpdate module. However, I'm encountering some difficulties when it comes to hiding Windows updates using PSWindowsUpdate. It seems simple enough according to the various online articles/documentation I've read, but for some reason is not working for me. I've specifically referenced [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849471/pswindowsupdate-cant-hide-an-update) and have attempted to apply the accepted answer as my solution, but no beef. The answer here also doesn't quite get at what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me provide some background first:

**BACKGROUND**

I have 5 Windows 10 Pro systems and 11 Windows 7 Pro systems. All are 64-bit. The Windows 7 systems have all been updated previously to WMF 5.1. I am using Remote Desktop Enterprise Edition to execute scripts on multiple computers simultaneously to help me streamline the update process.

**WHAT I'VE ATTEMPTED**

I've spent a fair amount of time attempting to solve my own problem through various Google searches and trial and error with my PS script. When I execute the script on my remote machines, everything runs and updates just fine. The problem, as I've already mentioned, is that it doesn't always hide Windows Updates that I've specified (since I'm probably messing up somewhere haha). Here's my script:

```
#This script will update all chocolatey packages and will also download install any new Windows Updates

#Begin ExecutionPolicy Set
Echo "Setting Execution Policy Settings"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Confirm:$false

Echo "Initializing Unattended Update Automation Powershell Script"

#Begin Chocolatey Update
Echo "Updating Chocolatey Packages"

#Remove Java and reinstall 64-bit  only
cuninst jre8 -y
cinst jre8 -PackageParameters "/exclude:32" -y

#Queries Chocolatey.org database for updates to locally installed packages and updates them if necessary
cup all -y --ignore-checksums

#Begin Windows Update
Echo "Enabling Windows Update Services"
Get-Service bits, wuauserv | Set-Service -StartupType manual

Echo "Copying Module PSWindowsUpdate to PowerShell Modules Folder"
#Grabs copy of PSWindowsUpdate Module and copies it to remote machine
Copy-Item -Path \\DIROFFICE\WindowsUpdate\PSWindowsUpdate -Destination C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -recurse -force

Echo "Importing Powershell Module PSWindowsUpdate"
Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -force
refreshenv

Echo "Enabling updates for additional Microsoft components and software"
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false

Echo "Querying Microsoft Update Server for Windows Updates"
Get-WUList -MicrosoftUpdate

Echo "Hiding Unnecessary Updates"
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Update for Microsoft OneDrive" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false

Echo "Downloading and Installing Windows Updates"
Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -acceptall

Echo "Stopping Windows Update Services"
Get-Service bits,wuauserv | Stop-Service

Echo "Setting CurrentUser Execution Policy Back to RemoteSigned"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Confirm:$false
```

**THE PROBLEM/QUESTION**

What I want to ultimately accomplish is hide certain updates based on certain keywords that appear in the title of the update. For example, we have Microsoft 2016 installed on all our computers, but I want to be able to hide all Outlook, OneDrive, Visio, and Skype updates on both W10 and W7 machines, and also Microsoft Security Essentials on W7 machines. Is there an effective way to use the PSWindowsUpdate module to hide updates the contain certain words?

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

The small line of code listed in my script under the hiding updates section is there simply for testing purposes. I initially tried to hide updates by using the full title of said update. For example, there were numerous updates for Outlook 2016 where the title was either "Security update for Microsoft Outlook 2016" or just plain "Update for Microsoft Outlook 2016." I tried using `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Update for Microsoft Outlook" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false` as well as `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Security update for Microsoft Outlook" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false`. This doesn't appear to work as when I viewed my installed updates it showed that 4 or 5 updates for Microsoft Outlook were installed.

I also tried using the wildcard (*), but don't think I fully understand how it works. I attempted a few things like `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Update for Microsoft Outlook*" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false` and `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Outlook*" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false`. I even tried a double wildcard with something like `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*Microsoft Oulook*" -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false`.

From what I've read on TechNet and MSDN, the (*) wildcard will match characters starting at the specified position. Does this break down if there are spaces included?

Using the KB Article ID isn't my preferred method since I would have to update my script every time with the new KB IDs I need to hide. I'd much prefer the keyword approach if at all possible. I did try using the method listed in the above Stackoverflow reference just for grins and giggles, but it's not ultimately the solution I'm looking for right now.

Comment: This seems to be just a minor syntax issue. Could you list what you want to hide first with `Get-WUList`, then pipe to `Hide-WUUpdate`? It's sometimes easier to identify your objects in the beginning part of the statement since you can remove the pipe (and everything after it) to first confirm that your query selects the correct objects. Much like `Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process`.

Comment: Ok. I'm not 100% sure how to do that since I'm a PS infant, but I'll see if I can figure it out and get back to you.

Comment: @root Is there a way to use get-wulist to search for multiple update titles containing a certain string at the same time? I tried creating an array $UpdateTitles = "Update for Skype", "Update for Microsoft Visio", "Update for Microsoft Outlook", but when I then use Get-WUList -Title $UpdateTitles I receive an error message that says it can't covert it to a System.String.

Comment: `Get-WUList | Where-Object { $_.Title -like "*Skype*" -or $_.Title -like "*Visio*" -or $_.Title -like "*Outlook*" }`

Comment: @root Awesome. Thanks. I was just reading about the `-match` and `-like` and `-contains` switches. So then from there I could just add `|Hide-WUUpdate` at the end to hide all of the updates containing those word, correct?

Comment: Hmm. Well, I just tried adding `|Hide-WUUpdate` on the end and it hid everything and not just the items specified so I'm probably doing it wrong :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to hide them all in one step? Is there a downside in your case to using `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "foo"` for each update individually? The module may be designed to handle multiple entries, I'd have to install it

Comment: Not necessarily, no. In your original comment you said I could list them and then pipe them to `Hide-WUUpdate`, so I guess I interpreted that as being the best way to do it. When I use the `where-object` statement you provided, it does correctly query the updates so it just seems strange that piping them to Hide-WUUpdate doesn't work. Anyway, out of curiosity, where does the $_.Title come from in the `Where-Object` statement? (I'd vote your comment up, but can't since I'm a noob :/)

Comment: All at once is obviously optimal, but if not necessary, you might progress more quickly if you hide updates individually. I recommend not spending too much time on particulars with custom PS modules. `$_` is the current object. For example, try running `1,2,3 | Foreach-Object { Write-Host "current number:" $_ }`. You'll see that for each object, we write the string appended with the current object (1, then 2, then 3). The `.` can be used after an object to specify a property. `$_.Title` in the example above queries the "Title" property of each object.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. If you want to move your first comment and your second comment to an actual answer I will accept it as it ultimately was what I was looking for I can edit my question to reflect that there a some difficulties in piping a list of what updates to hide as the module doesn't appear to totally support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hide-WUUpdate` may not support updating multiple records at once.

A common approach to this in Powershell is to narrow your objects down in the front of the pipeline, then sending them to your action at the end of the pipeline (eg `Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process`). This will only apply to this scenario if `Hide-WUUpdate` accepts objects as input. It may not, only allowing use with its `-Title` flag, which may not support multiple entries.